# Deny access to HTML file if the user did not log in using PHP sessions

Tags: php, html, session

I've been trying to verify if the user is logged in when they access a certain html file.

For example if the user didn't log in and he is accessing something.html I want to redirect him to index.php and deny the access to something.html until he logs in.

I've been using sessions to keep track of the user that logged in. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You are on the right track, thats how I would do it.  I also store the timestamp at login and at every page change.  At the start of the new page I check that value to seee how long ago they last changed a page.  If its been too long I redirect them to login.  You can also use javascript to do timeouts on the client side.

Comment: Using an `.html` would require you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Otherwise, you're better off using all `.php` file extensions. Anyone would be able to access something.html without doing that. You could try using `.htaccess` but it's not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

create a .htaccess in that folder

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Then add this to each html:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logined']) || $_SESSION['logined'] === FALSE){
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }
?>
Then follows your original HTML content
<html> ......
```

Idea from fred-ii:

> You can also limit it to just a single file instead of the entire folder.

In this way, use this in your .htaccess instead

```
<Files yourhtmlFilname.html> 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

Or specific multiple files:

```
<FilesMatch "^(file_one|file_two|file_three)\.html$">
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</FilesMatch>
```

I just tested, other html files under that folder won't run as PHP.

Comment: [We think alike...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836687/deny-access-to-html-file-if-the-user-did-not-log-in-using-php-sessions#comment47800185_29836687) quite coincidental ;-)

Comment: You can also limit it to just a single file instead of the entire folder.

Comment: well, this method is quite stupid (when there are many such html files) and may cause security issues in some case(when users are allowed to upload or modify your html file by any means)

Comment: An additional resource http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logined']) || $_SESSION['logined'] === FALSE){
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }
?>
```

As mentioned by Shiji Jiang, or alternatively, if you happen to be using php include to show pages you can do this:

```
<?php
//parent page
$inpage = true;

include 'subpage.php';

?>
```

This will allow you to control pages whether a user is logged in or not, and web crawlers won't be able to scrape your page, but a user doesn't have to be logged in to see it either.

```
<?php
//sub page
if($inpage != true){
header("Location: index.php");
die();
}

?>
```